# excel like calculations in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

[image]

If there are two columns id1 & id2 with values shown, is it possible for mysql to join these two (ADD the two fields) & into a 3rd one id.

(So easy to do it in excel - using a formula which takes values from two columns of an excel table & performs the calculation in the 3rd). Thanks

Comment: you can use concat() function available with mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do.

```
select firstCol, secondCol, concat(firstCol, secondCol) as thirdCol
from table name
```

Comment: Can it be done at the time the data is being inserted? i.e. using an INSERT command?

Comment: well, at that time, you can easily do like insert into tablename(firstCol, secondCol, thirdCol) values ($firstCol, $secondCol, $thirdCol); while you need define #thirdCol = $firstCol.' '.$secondCol;

Comment: define $thirdCol = $firstCol.' '.$secondCol in php  or such server language you mean

Comment: Yes in PHP. which language you want to do ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:
If you want to concat the string you can do like below:

```
update table set id = concat(id1,id2);
```

If you want to add :

```
update table set id = (id1+id2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.